# pairwise subtraction of rows of an array and division in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have three arrays called flow_stress(4x3) and strain_rate(1x4) and T(1x3). I have interpolated the log of flow_stress with respect to [Temp = 1000/(T+273) which is line spaced into 50 terms] and with respect to srate (which is log of strain rate line-spaced into 100 terms) such that the flow_stress3 is an array of (100x50)
I am trying to create an array **m**   which is equal to the (difference of consecutive rows of flow_stress3) divided by (difference of consecutive terms of srate).
Though the array flow_stress3 and array srate have correct values . values of m are wrong.

```
>import numpy as np

>import math

>from scipy import interpolate as sp

>import matplotlib as plt

>T = np.array([750,800,850])           
  ## Enter temperature value in degree##

>strain_rate = np.array([0.0003,0.001,0.01,0.1])   

>flow_stress = np.array([[95.96, 49.46,28.16],\
                        [126.62,80.51,46.45],\
                        [235.14,151.46,107.94],\
                        [319.15,228.77,165.63]])


>Temp = 1000/(273+T)

>k = (max(T)-min(T))/2

>TT = np. linspace(max(Temp), min(Temp),k)          
 ## divide the temp into k##

>S = np.log10(flow_stress)

>flow_stress1 = np.empty(shape=[len(strain_rate),len(TT)]) 

 ## makes an empty array of dim ##

>(len(strain_rate),len(TT))

>SR= np.log10(strain_rate)

>n = (max(SR)-min(SR))/0.025        
 ## divide SR by 0.025 to get number of terms in matrix##

>l = n//1                           
 ## operator // converts the fraction into integer##

>srate= np.linspace(min(SR), max(SR),l)     

## divides SR into l equal no of parts##

>len_srate = len(srate)

>for i in range(len(strain_rate)):          
 ## first interpolate between temp and log flow stress ##
 >>   f_linear = sp.interp1d(Temp,S[i,:])
 >>  flow_stress1[i,:] = f_linear(TT)                
 ## interpolate at values given by TT ##

>flow_stress2 = np.empty(shape=[len(TT),len(srate)])

>for i in range(len(TT)):
>>f_linear = sp.interp1d(SR,flow_stress1[:,i])
>>flow_stress2[i,:] = f_linear(srate)

>flow_stress3 = flow_stress2.T

>print(len(flow_stress3))
>print(len(flow_stress3[0,:]))
>print(len(srate))
>print(len(TT))

>srate = srate.T


>m = np.zeros(shape=[len(srate),len(TT)],dtype=np.ndarray)

>for i in range(len(srate)-1):
>>m[i,:]= np.array((flow_stress3[i+1,:]-flow_stress3[i,:])/(srate[i+1]-srate[i]))

>m[len(srate)-1,:] = m[len(srate)-2,:]
```

I get a contour plot of m with respect to srate and T as like under in fig1 . 
A plot with same data done in MatLab is also shown in next fig 2 . we know for sure that MatLab data is correct. With Python, as can be seen value of many raws and columns are identical which should not be the case.
[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbjsX.png)

[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Z2D.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of where the numbers are wrong? Are all rows wrong, and all columns?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question. I get a contour plot of m with respect to srate and T as like under in fig1(Please look edited question) . A plot with same data done in MatLab is also shown in next fig 2 . we know for sure that MatLab data is correct. With Python, as can be seen value of many raws and columns are identical which should not be the case.

Comment: You say that `srate` and `flow_stress3` are correct, but they do contain repeated rows too, so the error comes earlier than the computation of `m`.

Comment: Ah, so this was originally written in MATLAB? I would not generally recommend translating them directly, because Python syntax is often quite different and translating from MATLAB, C etc often becomes inefficient and the power of Python is underutilised.

Comment: As for identical rows, the last line seems to be doing just that, isn't it?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson, the flow_stress3 do not have repeated rows and have correct values only. somhow, the problem occurs while using the last for loop where i do not get correct m values.

Comment: @user153812 , last row was made equal to second last intentionally, since we cant get derivative of last row using the for loop . though it wont have any significant effect of my result.

Comment: Um, in that case maybe you should re-visit the basics of central difference method and forward/backward difference methods for finding gradient, and implement in your algorithm such that end points use forward/backward difference, while remaining points use central difference. Of course, there are functions available to do this already, but it may be instructional to do it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick. The flow_stress3 rows vary, but the differences between adjacent rows are the same for a lot of rows, which gives a constant result.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson , you are correct, the flow_stress3 values are incorrect and difference are constant. I used interpolate function which divides my array into homogeneous intervals. I will correct the mistake now.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the backslashes when you enter `flow_stress`. The value is not finished until the final bracket.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your requirement is simply to calculate the first derivative of flow_stress3 wrt srate. The code seems rather complex for that. In particular, I don't understand what purpose the last line serves.

Since you're already using scipy, I would suggest using the [UnivariateSpline function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative.html). Your code will shrink to something like:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

splinecoeff=UnivariateSpline(srate,flow_stress3)
m=splinecoeff.derivative()
```